# Trying to get the position of an SVG object inside a table using jquery .offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a html file with SVG objects inside a table layout. I have made these SVG objects draggable by using jQuery UI's `.draggable()`. My aim is to drag these elements around and send their positions back to the server using a HTTP POST. To find the positions I am using `.offset()`. When I see the data back in my server and use that data to reconstruct the positions I see that two objects `#head2` and `#shirt2` always end up having the same values.

```
var sh2 = $("#shirt2").offset();
var he1 = $("#head1").offset();
var he2 = $("#head2").offset();
var sh1 = $("#shirt1").offset();
document.getElementById('sh2l').value = parseInt(sh2.left);
document.getElementById('sh2t').value = parseInt(sh2.top);
document.getElementById('he1l').value = parseInt(he1.left);
document.getElementById('he1t').value = parseInt(he1.top);
document.getElementById('he2l').value = parseInt(he2.left);
document.getElementById('he2t').value = parseInt(he2.top);
document.getElementById('sh1l').value = parseInt(sh1.left);
document.getElementById('sh1t').value = parseInt(sh1.top);
alert("\nhe1l" + he1.left + "\nhe1t" + he1.top + "\nhe1l" + "\nhe1l");
document.getElementById("temp").submit();
```

```css
.window {
position: relative;
left:880px;
border: 5px solid red;
    width: 350px;
    height:450px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.top_bar {
    border: 3px dashed red;
    border-radius: 80px;
}
.menu
{
    position:relative;
    width:410px;
    height:420px;
    bottom:450px;
    left:80px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.bottom
{
position:relative;
    width:40px;
    height:20px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    left:610px;
    bottom:600px;
    
}
#top
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
    font-size:40px;
}
#head1
{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
#head2
{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
#shirt1
{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
#shirt2
{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
height:200px;
}
.comic_button
{
width:150px;
height:80px;
border: 4px dashed red;
text-align: center;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
    font-size:30px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
input
{
margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stick.css">
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#head1").draggable();
        $("#head2").draggable();
        $("#shirt1").draggable();
        $("#shirt2").draggable();
    });
   
    function clicker() {
        var sh2 = $("#shirt2").offset();
        var he1 = $("#head1").offset();
        var he2 = $("#head2").offset();
        var sh1 = $("#shirt1").offset();
        document.getElementById('sh2l').value = parseInt(sh2.left);
        document.getElementById('sh2t').value = parseInt(sh2.top);
        document.getElementById('he1l').value = parseInt(he1.left);
        document.getElementById('he1t').value = parseInt(he1.top);
        document.getElementById('he2l').value = parseInt(he2.left);
        document.getElementById('he2t').value = parseInt(he2.top);
        document.getElementById('sh1l').value = parseInt(sh1.left);
        document.getElementById('sh1t').value = parseInt(sh1.top);
        alert("\nhe1l" + he1.left + "\nhe1t" + he1.top + "\nhe1l" + "\nhe1l");
        document.getElementById("temp").submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="height:800px; width:1340px;">
    <div class="top_bar">
        <h1 id="top">STICK MAN</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="window">
        <svg width="350" height="450" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
            <g>
                <title>Layer 1</title>
                <line id="svg_3" y2="215" x2="193" y1="138" x1="192" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                <line id="svg_4" y2="300" x2="170" y1="207" x1="193" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                <line id="svg_5" y2="306" x2="219" y1="214" x1="193" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                <line id="svg_6" y2="163" x2="132" y1="162" x1="193" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                <line id="svg_7" y2="162" x2="253" y1="161" x1="192" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="head1">
                        <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
                        <g>
                            <title>Layer 1</title>
                            <ellipse ry="44" rx="44" id="svg_8" cy="129" cx="92" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <line id="svg_15" y2="97" x2="21" y1="98" x1="163" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <path d="m60,95c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-2 0,-3 0,-5c0,-3 0,-5 0,-6c0,-3 0,-4 0,-5c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-3 1,-4 1,-5c0,-1 0,-2 0,-4c0,-2 1,-3 1,-6c0,-1 0.4588,-1.69344 1,-3c0.38269,-0.92387 1,-5 1,-6c0,-1 2.29291,-0.29289 3,-1c0.70709,-0.70711 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 2,-2 3,-2c1,0 2.69345,-0.4588 4,-1c0.92389,-0.38269 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2.01291,-0.16019 3,0c3.12143,0.50655 4,1 6,1c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2.29291,-0.70711 3,0c0.70709,0.70711 1.02676,0.77025 2,1c2.17624,0.51375 2.4588,1.69344 3,3c0.38269,0.92387 0,2 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 -0.70709,2.29289 0,3c0.70709,0.70711 1,1 1,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,2 1,4 1,5c0,1 0,5 0,8c0,1 0,2 0,4c0,2 0,3 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3l1,0" id="svg_16" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#bf5f00" />
                            <path d="m67,112c0,0 0,0 1,0c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0l1,0l1,0l0,1" id="svg_19" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <path d="m99,113c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 1.61731,-0.07612 2,-1c0.5412,-1.30656 2,-2 3,-2c1,0 2.58578,1.41422 4,0c0.70711,-0.70711 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 2,0 3,0l1,0l2,0" id="svg_20" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <polyline stroke-width="6" id="svg_21" points="74,119 74,119 74,119 " stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <polyline id="svg_22" points="112,123 112,123 " stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="8" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <line id="svg_23" y2="144" x2="72" y1="137" x1="105" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="head2">
                        <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
                        <g>
                            <title>Layer 1</title>
                            <ellipse ry="44" rx="44" id="svg_8" cy="129" cx="92" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <line id="svg_15" y2="97" x2="21" y1="98" x1="163" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <path d="m60,95c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-2 0,-3 0,-5c0,-3 0,-5 0,-6c0,-3 0,-4 0,-5c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-3 1,-4 1,-5c0,-1 0,-2 0,-4c0,-2 1,-3 1,-6c0,-1 0.4588,-1.69344 1,-3c0.38269,-0.92387 1,-5 1,-6c0,-1 2.29291,-0.29289 3,-1c0.70709,-0.70711 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 2,-2 3,-2c1,0 2.69345,-0.4588 4,-1c0.92389,-0.38269 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2.01291,-0.16019 3,0c3.12143,0.50655 4,1 6,1c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2.29291,-0.70711 3,0c0.70709,0.70711 1.02676,0.77025 2,1c2.17624,0.51375 2.4588,1.69344 3,3c0.38269,0.92387 0,2 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 -0.70709,2.29289 0,3c0.70709,0.70711 1,1 1,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,2 1,4 1,5c0,1 0,5 0,8c0,1 0,2 0,4c0,2 0,3 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3l1,0" id="svg_16" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#bf5f00" />
                            <path d="m67,112c0,0 0,0 1,0c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0l1,0l1,0l0,1" id="svg_19" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <polyline stroke-width="6" id="svg_21" points="74,119 74,119 74,119 " stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <path d="m105,112c0,0 0,0 1,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c2,0 3,-1 4,-1l1,0l1,0" id="svg_24" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <polyline id="svg_25" points="110,118 110,118 " stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="6" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <polyline id="svg_26" points="75,120 75,120 " stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="6" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <polyline id="svg_27" points="109,120 109,120 " stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <path d="m108,137c0,0 -0.29289,-0.70711 -1,0c-0.70711,0.70711 -0.29289,1.29289 -1,2c-0.70711,0.70711 -1.29289,0.29289 -2,1c-0.70711,0.70711 -0.29289,1.29289 -1,2c-0.70711,0.70711 -2,0 -4,0c-1,0 -1,1 -2,1c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -3,0 -4,0c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2,0 -4,0c-1,0 -1,-1 -1,-2c0,-1 -1,-1 -1,-2l-1,0l0,-2l0,1" id="svg_28" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <rect id="svg_29" height="15" width="24" y="109" x="62" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <rect id="svg_30" height="17" width="25" y="108" x="97" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <line id="svg_31" y2="118" x2="100" y1="118" x1="85" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <line id="svg_32" y2="108" x2="133" y1="117" x1="124" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                            <line id="svg_33" y2="107" x2="53" y1="116" x1="61" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="shirt1">
                        <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
                        <g>
                            <title>Layer 1</title>
                            <rect id="svg_2" height="16" width="0" y="61" x="62" stroke-width="5" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#FF0000" />
                            <rect id="svg_3" height="70" width="50" y="50" x="70" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#FF0000" />
                            <rect id="svg_4" height="10" width="30" y="50" x="110" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#FF0000" />
                            <rect id="svg_5" height="10" width="30" y="50" x="50" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#FF0000" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="shirt2">
                        <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
                        <g>
                            <title>Layer 1</title>
                            <rect id="svg_2" height="16" width="0" y="61" x="62" stroke-width="5" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#FF0000" />
                            <rect id="svg_3" height="70" width="50" y="50" x="70" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00bf00" fill="#00bf00" />
                            <rect id="svg_4" height="10" width="30" y="50" x="110" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00bf00" fill="#00bf00" />
                            <rect id="svg_5" height="10" width="30" y="50" x="50" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00bf00" fill="#00bf00" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <form name="cgx" method="POST" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.pl" class="bottom" id="temp">
        <input type="hidden" id="he1l" name="he1l">
        <input type="hidden" id="he1t" name="he1t">
        <input type="hidden" id="he2l" name="he2l">
        <input type="hidden" id="he2t" name="he2t">
        <input type="hidden" id="sh1l" name="sh1l">
        <input type="hidden" id="sh1t" name="sh1t">
        <input type="hidden" id="sh2l" name="sh2l">
        <input type="hidden" id="sh2t" name="sh2t">
        <input type="test" placeholder="enter name for your design" name="file_name">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" class="comic_button" id="joma" name="jomakoreje" value="submit" onclick="clicker()">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use position(); if you need position relative to parent element

Comment: i used position() too;even then these two svgs end up having same values.

Comment: I never use tables, maybe the table is causing this?

Comment: This is not reproducible for me. The client side seems to work fine. Where do things get messy, on the client or on the server?

Comment: @RensTillmann thanks for the suggestion i will remove the table and use a div based layout to see if it changes

Comment: @altocumulus i think the problem is on the client side.if i use an alert at the end of the function onclick() to see the position values before submitting even then those two objects have similar position even though they are in different locations on the screen.

Comment: Then maybe try on the div element instead? Weird though.

Comment: Even if I do a `console.log()` for all positions I end up with perfectly distinct values corresponding to each element's position. The `.top` values are obviously the same at the start, but, when dragging around, they are adjusted accordingly.

Comment: In such situation I would make a simple test with just 2 times 2 elements and see what you can get. And from their build it up till you got what you need. Also the rendering might be later than doc ready. Same happens with some fonts. When you determine an object with a special font it first gets the height of it with regular font, but when page has loaded the height has become larger because font initialized, maybe same kinda thing happening here?

Comment: Oh nvm that cant be it :p

Comment: I see 1 thing, and that is that the values are correctly updated to the form. Only I cannot determine what the POST actually sends in console cause it is in sandbox mode. Anyway I guess that should be alright. Then there is only one thing that could be wrong at this point. That is when retrieving your saved data. You save it into a database and then you retrieve it? These values are the same as when submitted? If so than the only thing that is going wrong is positioning the SVG object. Put `style="position: relative; left: 594px; top: -55px;"` with the correct values should work?

Comment: you all were right,it was due to a lousy mistake in my backend perl code.Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Please update your question and provide an answer with the solution in case there is anything others could learn from that. If it really was just a *lousy mistake*, you might want to consider deleting it altogether.